# wrong class design need a refactoring

Tags: delphi

On a complex application I found  a small mistake in respect to class design :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;


type AboutMe= class
      Name : String
      end;

type AboutMe_more  = class(AboutMe)
       gender : String;
       Birth  : TDate;
end;

type Aboutme_complete = class (AboutMe_more)
       adresss : String;
       salery : Real;
       name : String;   ///  name is already available a parent class
       end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var  _Aboutme_complete : Aboutme_complete ;
begin
     _Aboutme_complete := Aboutme_complete.Create;
     _Aboutme_complete.name := 'a coding error -> need refactoring ';
end;

end.
```

In the class "AboutMe_more", by mistake the field name has been added. 
I wonder what kind of error might happen if I remove that obsolete name field?
The trouble behind that question ( ~ 100 K Lines of code and no systematic test)

Comment: If you (who can access the code to see what the impact would be) can't tell, how in the world would you expect **us** to be able to do so? If you're using a modern version of Delphi, use the Refactoring menu to change the field name, choose to preview changes first, and look and see what changes are necessary. You'll then have the information to use to evaluate what impact the changes will make on the code that *you have access to and we don't*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two separate variables named `name` in the type `Aboutme_complete`. There is one introduced in `AboutMe` and then a second introduced in `Aboutme_complete` which hides the first.

- For methods of `AboutMe`, the member `name` refers to the first variable.
- For methods of `Aboutme_complete`, the member `name` refers to the second variable.

Removing the variable `name` from `Aboutme_complete` will likely change behaviour. That's because there would now be just a single variable, and methods of all the classes would be referring to the same variable. So, as the code stands, methods in `Aboutme_complete` refer to `Aboutme_complete.name`, but if you made the change the code would then refer to `AboutMe.name`.

Whether this breaks your code depends on what the code is. Only you can know the answer to that because only you have that code.